# Tampermonkey script gives "targetNode.dispatchEvent is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I want to click a button using Tampermonkey, but get this error:

> userscript.html?id=2514f475-79e4-4e83-a523-6fef16dceeaa:10617 Uncaught TypeError: targetNode.dispatchEvent is not a function at triggerMouseEvent...

My script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Lootbits
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       Zan Draklar
// @match        https://lootbits.io/*
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js
// ==/UserScript==

var gems = 0

$(document).ready(function() { 
    if($('#claimbtn').length) {
        simulateMouseClick('#claimbtn');
    }
})
function simulateMouseClick(targetNode) {
    function triggerMouseEvent(targetNode, eventType) {
        var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        clickEvent.initEvent(eventType, true, true);
        targetNode.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    }
    ["mouseover", "mousedown", "mouseup", "click"].forEach(function(eventType) {
        triggerMouseEvent(targetNode, eventType);
    });
}
setInterval(function() {
    $("#lootbits").val(function(e) {
        gems = $(this).text();
    });
    if(gems>0) {
        $('#lootboxout > div > div > div.lootbox-side.lootbox-side-front').click()
    }
}, 2000);
setInterval(function() {
    location.reload()
}, 605000);
```

Comment: Are you certain that `targetNode` is not null and properly defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:
simulateMouseClick('#claimbtn');
to:
simulateMouseClick($('#claimbtn'));

Change:
targetNode.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
to:
document.querySelector("#claimbtn").dispatchEvent(clickEvent);

Answer (score 0):

In your triggerMouseEvent function you have to use a query selector to target the element. You cannot pass an element by reference.

Comment: I'm new to jquery and tampermonkey, can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: @zandrakslar in your triggerMouseEvent() function you are currently passing a reference to a DOM node which was assigned to var claimBtnNd via your jQuery selector. That node, claimBtnNd is now being passed via reference to simulateMouseClick(). In order to access any properties on the element you will need to select it via jQuery again. You can accomplish this by passing the name of the target node via string into triggerMouseEvent() instead of the target node.